# Getting the right regex -- Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to parse the output of [cflow](http://www.gnu.org/software/cflow/), which will then be used to construct a 3D graph of control flow. The output of cflow looks something like this:

```
main() <int main (int argc, char *argv[]) at sort.c:3>:
    strcmp()
    printf()
    malloc()
    getline() <char *getline (int max) at sort.c:62>:
        isspace()
        getchar()
        ungetc()
        malloc()
    qsort()
    free()
```

I'm using regular expressions to extract the function name and parentheses -- I want to get `main()`, `strcmp()`, etc. My code is as follows:

```
String line = input.nextLine(); // input is a Scanner reading from a file
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\(\\)"); // the important part
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
```

Now, the pattern I'm using works using Emacs' regexp-builder mode. Yet when I run this program, I don't get any matches. I'm probably just not understanding Java's regex functions.

Also, I realize that the obvious solution is to just not use Java... I'd prefer that, but I'm going to draw the graph with Processing, so I don't really have a choice.

Comment: I'd just count the leading spaces to determine how deep in the tree it is and strip the leading spaces for the function name, chopping anything after the argument parens.

Comment: I realize I can do it with normal string manipulation, but it seems somewhat more elegant to do it with a regex. As the Eleventh Doctor might say, regexes are _cool_.

Comment: How are you trying to get the matches? what Matcher method?

Comment: Your code works just fine: http://ideone.com/OZDoV

Comment: A-ha! I didn't realize that I had to call `m.find()` before getting the match. Thanks!

Comment: How is it more elegant to do something slower and more complex than necessary? Seems like the opposite to me, but perhaps I'm just backwards. The regex doesn't count the spaces anyway, so you're *really* not gaining anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to extract part of the string, you have to use parentheses to form groups in the regular expression. If you rewrote your regular expression to be something like `.*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\(\\)).*`, the group in the literal parentheses is actually stored as a match. You would then call `m.group(1)` to retrieve the string extracted by the first parenthetical group, which is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\(\\)`.

Answer (score 0):

With your current syntax and `m.matches()`, Java assumes you mean:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\(\\)$");
```

So, you need to add wildcards to the start and end of your expression (I've wrapped the part you wish to match in parenthesis)

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\(\\)).*");
```

Or call `m.find()` instead of `m.matches()`.

You can now call:

```
if(m.matches())
{
    myFunctionName = m.group(1);
}
```